# Command Block working after breaking it

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Recently I made a command block teleporting player to specific cords but i accidentaly turned it ON and I was stuck in a loop. I destroyed the command block with setblock but it still executed commands.

I checked it with NBT Editor and it wasn't in the region files but still teleported me. I am using Java edition 1.16.5

Comment: What edition are you playing on?

Comment: Java Edition 1.16.5

Comment: Did you try restarting minecraft/server ? I am pretty sure that should work, but if not, then I guess reporting to the hosting website if you use one or Mojang should help you.

Answer (score 2):

you could do /commandblocksenabled false and that would stop command blocks to execute their command and then break the block where the command block was changed